# After installing fresh version of magento 2.17 styles.css file not found

Tags: magento2

After installing Magento 2 CE (version 2.17) fresh version. I found following 404 error of the path on following directory pub/media/styles.css.
I found some solution over the internet and I tried that, but no one is work for me.
Then on the admin panel, **Content->Design->Configuration** and on the HTML Head section's "Scripts and Style Sheets" field I found following code

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="{{MEDIA_URL}}styles.css" />
```

But on the following directory, no file exists.

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Remove all files with in static folder, not **.htaccess**, /pub/static/* file.  and remove all file with in var/*

Then run,

```
 <mage-root>  rm -rf var/*
 <mage-root>php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
 <mage-root>php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Clear cache, Then check it.

Comment: Thanks @Rajkumar for the reply.
But not works for me.
the problem is on directory
pub/media/
not pub/static.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is some issue with Magento version or permission, I used this file to load the layout.

https://equaltrue.com/resource/magento/magento2/pub/media/styles.css

Upload the file on root to pub/media